# Inserting quote into string produces two quotes

Tags: vb.net

I want to include a " symbol within a string.  So first I just included a double quote like this:

`Dim strRequest As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>`

But that produced a double quote in the string which I did not expect at all.

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
```

So I went so far as to do this:

```
Dim strRequest As String = "<?xml version="
strRequest &= Chr(34)
strRequest &= "1.0"
```

But I'm still getting double quotes.  Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: about the double quote missing at the end of `Dim strRequest As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>`: is it just a typo?

Comment: Yes, a typo.  Bad copy and paste.

Comment: Why are you not using XML literals?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Visual Studio makes things a bit confusing for you:

On one hand, in debug mode (when hovering the variable) it is showing you this string: `"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"`.

On the other hand, and what it really holds internally as a value is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` (which is your desired result).

To test it: if instead of just hovering `strRequest` you use the Text Visualizer (the magnifying glass icon) you will see the desired result: `<?xml version=1.0 encoding=utf-8 ?>`.

Answer (score 1):

I've run this code:

```
Dim strRequest As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"
Console.WriteLine(strRequest)
```

I get this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

How do you know you still get the `""`?

I don't know why you don't do this:

```
Dim xml = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
    <data>Hello, this is some "quoted" text</data>
</root>
```

That directly gives me a `XDocument` object with all of the quotes working fine.

Comment: _How do you know you still get the ""?_ : my best guess is detailed in the other answer of this post. But you are right that he should probably use xml literals.